# Count Matches in an Array, Duplicates Once

Tags: excel

I have an array with a number of columns but am looking to count based on two columns in particular. I'm looking to have a function that will count how many blank products (column C) are in production (Column B). See image below, the desired output here would be 2 (111 and 333 are in production. 111 appears twice but should be counted only once).

[Case Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ2Lo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but this will get the job done.

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(C1:C4*--(B1:B4="In Production")))-1
```